# Scientific Journal

Tags: software, research, software-documentation

What are some other equivalents to a journal like SoftwareX where one can submit the methodology and codes used to solve a research problem?

Comment: I would advise you to submit your question on academic stack exchange. I would also advise you to give much more detail about what type of paper/subject area than you have here. Then you are more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Alright, I already did